# Submitting post variables from inside a php file

Tags: php

I was wondering if its possible to submit to a form from inside a php file?

Basically what i have to do is format some fields properly and then send them to a 3rd party via form action url which they have given.

If anyone could help me out, that would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Read about cURL http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+curl+post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php). [Here's](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html) a good tutorial talking about exactly what you want.